# How to load jdbc. properties file dynamically using spring?

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

My product is supported more than two databases.
I am using **common.properties** file in my product

Database config description are

```
Product.database=XXXX (oracle,postgres or mysql)
```

How to load the **XXXX**(database) jdbc.properties file dynamically?

It is possible. Help to me

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the [Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class, which provides a `load` method.

If you use the Spring Framework, maybe you want to have a look to the [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer)

Comment: Just to understand: are you trying to load properties directly, or do you want Spring framework to lead them for you?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly for my application, based on Spring + JPA + Hibernate. I'm using file properties
and let's Spring to read the properties, you can define multiple data source in spring xml configuration too.

**datasource.properties**

```
#Hibernate Properties
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
dataSource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
dataSource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myproject
dataSource.username=postgres
dataSource.password=123456
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"
default-autowire="byName">

<!--  import another XML configuration -->
<import resource="datasourceContext.xml"/>

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany"/>
<tx:annotation-driven  />
```

**datasourceContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"
default-autowire="byName">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:datasource.properties"/>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${dataSource.driverClassName}" p:url="${dataSource.url}"
    p:username="${dataSource.username}" p:password="${dataSource.password}" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPU" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
                p:database="POSTGRESQL" 
                p:showSql="true" 
                p:generateDdl="true" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

and here is the **persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com   
             /xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```